# VBA combine two loops into one message box

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the prompt: Find how many Zachary are in the list (using any loop you like) and the same time find how many customers are in the list

I was able to make two separate loops but they don't work in one message box when I try to combine them.

' Find how many Zachary are in the list (using any loop you like)

```
counter = 0
zCounter = 0

With Workbooks("C14-Do While Test - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Customers")

    Do While counter < 500
        counter = counter + 1

        If .Range("B1:B500").Cells(counter) = "Zachary" Then
            zCounter = zCounter + 1
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "There are " & zCounter & " Zacharys in the list"

End With
```

' and the same time find how many customers are in the list

```
counter = 0
notFound = True

With Workbooks("C14-Do While Test - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Customers")

    Do While notFound
        counter = counter + 1

        If .Range("B1:B500").Cells(counter) = "" Then
            notFound = False
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "There are " & counter & " customers in the list"

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which is only one loop and introduces a variable **`allCustomers`** to hold the count of customers which is assumed to be non-blank cells in loop range.

VBNewline is used with Msgbox to print both counts across separate lines.

```
counter = 0

zCounter = 0
allCustomers = 0 ' variable to hold all customers

With Workbooks("C14-Do While Test - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Customers")

    Do While counter < 500
        counter = counter + 1

        If .Range("B1:B500").Cells(counter) = "Zachary" Then
            zCounter = zCounter + 1
        End If

        If .Range("B1:B500").Cells(counter) <> vbNullString Then
            allCustomers = allCustomers + 1
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "There are " & zCounter & " Zacharys in the list" & vbNewLine &      "There are " & allCustomers & " customers in the list" 

End With
```

You could pull this `.Range("B1:B500").Cells(counter)` out into a variable to speed up your loop.

Comment: If it worked, accept the answer to allocate points to the donor.